# How to add loop for if condition?

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am using a shell script which need to enhaunce.

here is my script structure:

```
if [ condition 1 ] 
statement; 
exit; 
else if [ condition 2 ]   
statement;
exit;
else
sleep 30 
fi
```

I want to modify this script in such a way that if condition 2 is false it will go to else and wait for some time for condition 2 to become true and try it again after 30 seconds. This process should run 5 times. if still condtion 2 is false script should be exited.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shell script below maybe works as you desire

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ condition 1 ] 
  statement; 
  exit; 
fi

i=1
while [ $i -lt 5 ]
do
  if [ condition 2 ]   
    statement;
    exit;
  else
    sleep 30
    true $(( i++ )) 
  fi
done
```